# Useage of CSV for Django Rest Framework

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I've been trying to build a website with a backend via Django and a frontend via React. I would like to make it so users can see the contents of a CSV file. The Django rest framework site recommends using the following: https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv#readme

I was wondering if anyone had any examples of how to use this to turn into an api that can then be used on the frontend with react. I can't seem to find any examples of how to do this.

Comment: You can check out the example in the repository itself. https://github.com/mjumbewu/django-rest-framework-csv/blob/master/example/example/views.py